# Setting DPI for an image in Java

Tags: java, image, graphics2d

I want to convert a text string (a five digit number) to an image with low DPI (and consequently low size). I referred to some other posts on this site, but the code below, which I gathered from a similar post does not work for me. It runs fine, ans generates an image, but the image properties do not meet the DPI specifications given in the code.

I do not know why Java does not recognize these specifications while rendering the image, and would appreciate any ideas/comments. Are there any other ways to generate an image with high DPI or to tell Java what pixel size to use?
(I am using this image for Visual Crypto later and want to have low density in the original image for that reason). Thanks!

```
    String text = "12345";
    sFont font = new Font("TrueType", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 20);
    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO
            .getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier
            .createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier,
            param);
    int DPI = 10;
    double dotsPerMilli = DPI / 10 / 2.54;

    IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_1.0");
    IIOMetadataNode horiz = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
    horiz.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));
    IIOMetadataNode vert = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
    vert.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));
    IIOMetadataNode dim = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
    dim.appendChild(horiz);
    dim.appendChild(vert);
    root.appendChild(dim);
    metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_1.0", root);

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(30, 14, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream("C:\\imagefromtext.jpg"));
    writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(img, null, metadata), param);

    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

    g2d.setFont(font);
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    g2d.dispose();
    g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    g2d.setFont(font);
    fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
    g2d.dispose();
    return img;
```

Comment: I also want to add a comment that I am now thinking about in context with my question - when we set DPI or any other parameters for an image in Java, is it just writing that information to the metadata or does the image actually get recreated in accordance with those specifications?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say **image with high DPI (and consequently low size)**. High DPI does not equate to low size. The more DPI your image has the higher the size ...

Comment: My apologies - it should be low DPI, low size. I will edit my original question to correct it

Comment: I have also been conducting tests around this, and somehow when I look up properties of the generated image (using regular Windows-->Properties--> Details feature), its DPI does not match with what I set in the code, and the image size is also not reduced. (For instance, original image DPI is 96, and the generated image DPI is also 96, not 10 that I specified in my code). Am I overlooking something?